# Як перекласти слово "serendipity"

Tags: переклад, from-english

[Serendipity](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/serendipity) (англ.) - випадок, коли людина випадково знаходить цікаву або цінну річ (переклад мій).

Також додам ще приклад вживання із Кембріджського словника:

> One can go round making pleasant discoveries, which is surely the
>   correct description of **serendipity**.

Чи є якесь українське слово, яким можна перекласти "Serendipity"? Гугл пропонує **випадковість**, але в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/vypadkovistj) у цього слова немає потрібного значення (це просто якась непередбачуванна подія, слово "випадковість" не означає, що щось було знайдено) та "інтуїтивна прозорливість" (і хоч слово "прозорливість" є в СУМі, але воно означає "здатність передбачати на перед те, що має статися" - тому я також не бачу ніякого зв'язку із словом "Serendipity").

Словник [Мета](http://translate.meta.ua/ua/) також пропонує варіант "**інтуїтивна прозорливість**".
[Глосб](https://uk.glosbe.com/en/uk/Serendipity) пропонує:

**[Провидіння](http://sum.in.ua/s/PROVYDINNJa)** - це також радше передбачення, а не випадкова щаслива знахідка

**[Осяяння](http://sum.in.ua/s/OSJaJaNNJa)** - освідомлення.

Я припускаю, що, можливо, слово "[удача](http://sum.in.ua/s/udacha)" буде хорошим відповідником, однак я не впевненний.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Слово *serendipity* походить від [перської легенди про трьох принців з Серендипу](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Three_Princes_of_Serendip) (де Серендип — це назва острова [Шрі-Ланка, також відомого як Цейлон](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D1%80%D1%96-%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0), на класичній перській) і може означати, наскільки я можу судити з [Англійського Вікісловника](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/serendipity), три різні речі:

1. Неочікуване, непередбачене та/або несподіване, але щасливе відкриття та/або отримання досвіду, що відбувається випадково.
2. Сукупність подій, які не є корисними кожна окремо, але, коли трапляються разом, дають хороший або навіть чудовий результат.
3. *(рідко)* Те саме, що luck (щасливий випадок, удача, талан).

У випадках, коли потрібно точно зберегти конотацію оригіналу, іноді застосовують слово ***серенди́пність***, зокрема, наприклад:

- > Вдалі збіги, пов'язані з формою орбіти, масою Сонця тощо, називають зовнішніми, бо вони виникають із серендипності⁷ довколишнього середовища, а не з фундаментальних законів природи.
  >
  > —
  > <sub>7. Серендипність — щасливий випадок, осяяння, прорив, підказка інтуїції.</sub>
  >
  > //[Стівен Гокінґ, Леонард Млодінов «Великий замисел» у перекладі з англійської Миколи Климчука (Харків, «Клуб сімейного дозвілля», 2017), с. 135](//books.google.com/books?id=ThtFDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT135&dq=%22%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%967%22)
- > Винаходи не створюють у кабінетах за розкладом — це майже завжди результат *серендипності*, тобто щасливого випадку, осяяння, прориву, підказки інтуїції. Слово serendipity придумав письменник Г'ю Волпол (від назви казки «Троє принців із Серендипу» — там герої завдяки випадку й кмітливій голові постійно знаходили те, чого не шукали). Словом, ви знаходите щось, чого не шукали; це «щось» змінює світ, а ви дивуєтеся, чому ж одразу не додумалися до таких очевидних речей.  <…> Цей принцип годиться й у повсякденному житті: тримайте двері відкритими для серендипності.
  >
  > //[Насім Талеб «Чорний лебідь: Про (не)ймовірне у реальному житті», переклав з англійської Микола Климчук (Київ, «Наш формат», 2017), с. 192 і 231](//books.google.com/books?id=omcuDwAAQBAJ&q=%22%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96%22)
- > У дослідженнях мемуаристичної літератури актуальними й продуктивними є інші категорії: літературність, правдивість, щирість, дійсність, автентичність, виправдання, поезія і правда, самореферентність, серендипність тощо.
  >
  > //[Роман Гром'як «Терміносистеми сучасного літературознавства: досвід розробки і проблеми: Науковий семінар» (Тернопіль, Редакційно-видавничий відділ ТНПУ, 2006), с. 148](http://dspace.tnpu.edu.ua/bitstream/123456789/9147/1/Terminosust_seminar.pdf#page=148)
- > Серенди́пність (англ. serendipity) — явище випадкового знаходження чогось вдалого, особливо коли людина шукає щось інше.
  >
  > //[Вікіпедія, стаття «Серендипність»](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)
- > Уперше в українському літературознавстві актуалізовано філософсько-соціальну категорію авторитету у вимірі автобіографічного жанру та у
  >   порівнянні зосереджено увагу на автобіографічному аспекті біографічного
  >   авторитету Самчука та Канетті; поставлено проблему емансипації української
  >   автобіографії, а також проблему термінології автобіографічного жанру в
  >   контексті українських напрацювань із термінологічного апарату жанру
  >   мемуарів; підсумовано та узагальнено естетичні категорії автобіографічної
  >   літератури, в контексті автобіографії теоретично осмислено кінематографічну
  >   категорію серендипності як особливої форми жанрової відвертості, а також
  >   окреслено шляхи дослідження автобіографії як об’єкта провідних напрямів
  >   компаративістики.
  >
  > //[Андрій Цяпа «Автобіографія як проекція творця та національної літературно-культурної традиції (Улас Самчук, Еліас Канетті)» — автореферат
  >   дисертації на здобуття наукового ступеня кандидата філологічних наук (Тернопіль, 2006), с. 11](http://dspace.tnpu.edu.ua/bitstream/123456789/1527/1/%D0%A6%D1%8F%D0%BF%D0%B0%20%D0%90.%20%D0%93..pdf)
- [Стаття М. Собуцького «Кінопоетика за Арістотелем»](http://ekmair.ukma.edu.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/14038/Sobutskyi_Kinopoetyka_za_Aristotelem.pdf#page=4) посиланням № 27 посилається на статтю «Серендипність (Історії Альберта Майслсса)» у часописі «KINO-КОЛО» за 2001 № 12 с. 21, щоправда останню я знайти не можу.
- [Стаття О. Сусської «Трансформації соціології публічності на сучасному етапі розвитку соціологічної науки»](http://ekmair.ukma.edu.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/10891/Susska_Transformatsii_sotsiolohii_publichnosti.pdf), перекладаючи цитати з російського джерела № 19 (Цукерман Э. Новые соединения. Цифровые космополиты в коммуникативную эпоху / Этан Цукерман; пер. с англ. Д. Симановского. – М. : Ад Маргинем Пресс, 2015. – 336 с. : ил.), двічі передає російське слово [серенди́пность](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) (що найімовірніше зі свого боку є перекладом англійського serendipity) як серендипність.

Якщо ж є бажання перекласти хоч, можливо, частково з утратою точності, але без кальок, то можна спробувати якось так:

- коли мова про окремий випадок:

  - неочікувана/неждана/ненавмисна(/непередбачувана) вдала знахідка/відкриття/винахід;
  - щасливий збіг;
  - удача;
- коли мова про рису людини:

  - інтуїтивна прозорливість;
  - раптова кмітливість.